# Add chosen option in spinner into database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, spinner

I'm creating a signup page for my app. When users type their Username, password and email, it gets stored in my database. I also have a spinner for gender. How do I store what they chose for gender in my database? I'm relatively new to android programming, so go easy on me :(

My SignUp.Java

```
package com.nyp.integrateshoebox;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SignUp extends Activity {

TextView textView1, textView2, textView3, textView4, textView5, textView6;
EditText username, password, repassword, emailAddress;
Button signUp;
Spinner spinner1;
final Context context = this;
LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
public final Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
        "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    // get Instance  of Database Adapter
    loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
    loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();


username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
repassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
emailAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);

signUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String userName=username.getText().toString();
        String Password=password.getText().toString();
        String confirmPassword=repassword.getText().toString();
        String email=emailAddress.getText().toString();

        // check if any of the fields are vacant
        if(userName.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals("")||email.equals(""))
        {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill up empty fields!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
        }
        if( username.getText().toString().length() <= 6 )
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username has to be more than 6 character long!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
    else if( password.getText().toString().length() < 5 )
        {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password has to be more than 5 characters long!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
        }
        // check if both password matches
        if(!Password.equals(confirmPassword))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        else if( checkEmail(email) == false )
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Email Address!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirm?");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Are you sure the information is correct?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Created. Welcome to Shoebox!",
                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class);
                            startActivity(home);
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();

        }
        // Save the Data in Database
        loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(userName, Password,email);
    }
});

Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
String[] items = new String[]{"Male", "Female"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

    loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
}
private boolean checkEmail(String email) {
    return EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(email).matches();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sign_up, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And this is my LoginDataBaseAdpater.Java

```
package com.nyp.integrateshoebox;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter 
{
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
    // TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
    // SQL Statement to create a new database.
    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+
                                 "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text, EMAIL text); ";
    // Variable to hold the database instance
    public  SQLiteDatabase db;
    // Context of the application using the database.
    private final Context context;
    // Database open/upgrade helper
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    public  LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
    {
        context = _context;
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public  LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close() 
    {
        db.close();
    }

    public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
    {
        return db;
    }

    public void insertEntry(String userName,String password, String email)
    {
       ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
        newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);
        newValues.put("EMAIL", email);

        // Insert the row into your table
        db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);
        ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public int deleteEntry(String UserName)
    {
        //String id=String.valueOf(ID);
        String where="USERNAME=?";
        int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete("LOGIN", where, new String[]{UserName}) ;
       // Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
    }   
    public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
    {
        Cursor cursor=db.query("LOGIN", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
        cursor.close();
        return password;                
    }
    public void  updateEntry(String userName,String password, String email)
    {
        // Define the updated row content.
        ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        updatedValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
        updatedValues.put("PASSWORD",password);
        updatedValues.put("EMAIL",email);

        String where="USERNAME = ?";
        db.update("LOGIN",updatedValues, where, new String[]{userName});               
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new field to the table for the gender and pass the value from the spinner to the database.

1) Add the field to the table:

```
static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+ "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  text,PASSWORD text, EMAIL text, GENDER Integer); ";
```

2) Update your insert method:

```
public void insertEntry(String userName,String password, String email, int gender)
    {
       ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
        newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);
        newValues.put("EMAIL", email);
        newValues.put("GENDER", gender);

        // Insert the row into your table
        db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);
        ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

3) Get value from spinner and pass it to the insert method:
(uses [ISO 5218](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_5218))

```
Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
String strgender = (String) dropdown.getSelectedItem();
int gender = 0;
switch(strgender){
   case "Male":
     gender = 1;
     break;
   case "Female":
     gender = 2;
     break;
}

loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(userName, Password,email, gender);
```

Please note that you should add the new field to the updateEntry() method, too.